# ORB forwards to a wrong location

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, corba

I have an *orbd* started at a virtual host (with the IP *A*), with some remote object registered. Box that hosts virual boxes has IP *B*. When client tries to connect to the ORB at *A* to acquire the NamingContext, ORB replies with a LocationForward message poiniting to host *B* and port 1049 (like if another ORB would be started at that host). NamingContext is returned successfully, but obviously I'm not able to acqure the objects, registered at the NamingContext (at ORB hosted at *A*) by the name. 
Could anyone please explain what's happening? How can I access the orb hosted at *A* remotely?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you start up orbd? Did you use "-ORBInitialHost" to specify host A?

Comment: Yep, I tried to specify it, but no luck

Comment: I haven't tried this:

If you're using SUN's orb there's a property that allows you to control the hostname being used: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/jidlExceptions.html.

Other orb providers use different properties (e.g. com.ibm.CORBA.BootstrapHost)

Comment: Thx for the reply. Yes, I'm using default Sun ORB (bin/orbd). As far as I understand, specifying com.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost is equal to passing -ORBInitialHost in the arguments list.

Comment: No it's not equivalent: "To avoid the call to getHostName, you can set the following properties...". See the linked page above.

Comment: getLocalhost().getHostName() is called only if -ORBInitialHost or com.sun.CORBA.ORBServerHost is not specified explicitly. 
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/idl/orbd.html#starting At this page it's not said, if there's a difference between passing the host as an argument or as a property.

Comment: Do IP A and IP B resolve to different hostnames?

Comment: Yep, the hostnames are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently had a very similar problem. I had a setup with the ORB running on a virtual machine, and once it was starting, port 1049 at the host was opening, like it's another ORB running behind the default port. The problem in my case was the firewall, that blocked connections to this port. Once I've opened it, everything has started to work as it should.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your specific case, but, I see this behavior regularly on unix machines with java that have a bunged up /etc/hosts file.

For instance, assume the server with the orb on it is named "server.foo.com" in dns with an ip address of 192.168.0.2, but it's /etc/hosts file says "127.0.0.1 server server.foo.com".

When a client connects to the orb using dns to resolve server.foo.com, the orb reply back with 127.0.0.1, instead of 192.168.0.2.

The fix is to change /etc/hosts to have

127.0.0.1 localhost

192.168.0.2 server server.foo.com

Comment: thanks for reply! it seem to be right to the point - I'll verify it against my config today